# Mysql LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE scape character

Tags: mysql

I am loading data using the mysql command line

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/Users/roll/registros_tc3.csv' INTO TABLE `clientes` FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' ESCAPED BY '\\' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

The data loads fine but in the mysql interface there is an extra character at the end "`\r`" Is there a way to scape it?

Check screenshots

[image: The CSV file example]

[image: The mysql charactero at the end]

Thanks for any help.

Comment: your files are msdos text, which uses `\r\n` as the line terminator. since you told mysql that only `\n` is a terminator, the `\r` is considered part of the data

Comment: Niiceeee!! it works !!!  i was around 4 hours trying to gues why the f..ing \r apear at the end, thank broo. +100 for you.

Answer (score 0):

here the problem is with single and double quotes 
replace ESCAPED BY '\'  ---> here the it wont escape
use "" instead of single quotes hope this works

Comment: Thank John, the problem was as @Marc B suggested, i should use "\r\n" as the "end line"

Comment: Ya You are right  I thought the lines in the file don't have form feed character but it exists